# UIButton in UIScrollView->UIStackView->UIView not clicking

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7

I am having trouble figuring out why a UIButton will not click. I have a `UIScrollView` that contains a `UIStackView` where I am programmatically placing subviews. I am creating the subviews and placing them into the stack view with the following:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let vc0 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc0") as UIViewController!
        let vc1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc1") as UIViewController!

        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(vc0.view)
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(vc1.view)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        // mulitply by two in order to scale it to the size of each `addArrangedSubview`, subtract the height of the embedded navbar
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: stackView.frame.width * 2, height: stackView.frame.height - 64)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The only other changes I have made are with the constraints:
[image]

I should note that `vc0` and `vc1` are simple `UIView`s with a `UIButton` set to `show` another simple `UIView`.
Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
I have added a button to vc0 programmatically and the click is working. Why would this button work and one from storyboard not work?

```
...
    let vc0 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc0") as UIViewController!
...
    let btn=UIButton(type: .System)
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 32, 32)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "pressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    btn.setTitle("Press Me", forState: .Normal)
    vc0.view.addSubview(btw)
...
```

Comment: `vc0` and `vc1` appear in your code to be View Controllers, not `UIView`s

Probably would help to see the code for those too. `UIStackView` cannot contain `UIViewController`. This code probably couldn't even compile because the `addArrangedSubview` is expecting a `UIView`.

Comment: @shim there should have been a `.view` when adding them to the `UIStackView`. Which code would you like to see? I created them on the storyboard, added a button, and `ctrl` dragged to another view, and chose `show`. The controller code has not been modified.

Comment: I am currently facing exactly the same issue. Any new solutions for this problem? Creating the views for the StackView programmatically (without IB) is currently not an option for me.